# Can not mount NTFS Partition on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, mount, hard-drive

I installed Ubuntu 18.04-64bit with Windows 10-1809 and I can not mount 2 HDDs had been format with NTFS. I always get the error as below:
`mount: /mnt/DiskE: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

I had search around this forum and unix & linux exchange, However, no luck until now.
Here is some information I had read
[Problem mounting GPT disk partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126553/problem-mounting-gpt-disk-partition)
[mount command](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/mount.8.html)
[sfdisk command](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rLY5tnQTnrKNZIcWwM8M1FBl2gR_8YiW)
[parted command](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W4o9kLsKzMxiXDI4K8JO3WPZL3Aj4R8z)

2 HDDs has formatted with NTFS and `allocation unit` 128Kb, the SSD has installed Windows can mount normally and formatted with NTFS and `allocation unit` as default (4096 KB)

**Update:**
With suggestion of @oldfred, I found my Windows has Hibernate turn on. I turn it of, however, still no luck.
I already running `chkdsk` 2 times on 2 HDD drives. Here is the new log when I try to mount it

```
root@haiphan-desktop:~# mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda2 /media/haiphan/DriveD
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 32).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Do you have any idea how to about this problem? Any suggestion has appreciated

Comment: Is Windows fast start up on. It sets hibernation flag on all NTFS partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation  Also could be that NTFS needs chkdsk which you cannot do from Linux.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your information. First, my windows already turn off fast start up.  I recheck and found the hibernate is on. I turn it off and shutdown and start PC 2 times. But no luck. I running `chkdsk` 2 times. Still no luck now... I update some more information in my question

Comment: That is still typical of fast start up on or hibernation. Windows turns it back on with updates, so if it did an update before you shutdown, it may have just turned it back on again. Do not really know Windows but thought chkdsk fixed MFT type errors. You may have to run chkdsk until no errors.

Comment: Actually, when I run chkdsk for those HDDs, there is no error

Comment: I think I know the answer, however, It is not clue exactly the reason. I formatted one HDD with Windows 10, and default the cluster size `4096Kb` and I can mount it on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Formatted the HDD with Windows 10, and default the cluster size `4096KB`. Ubuntu 18.04 can mount it normally.
More information, Ubuntu 20.041 can mount the HDD format with 128KB without installing 3rd tool.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Should I write the title is NTFS instead GPT? Is it more clear?